# Beginner programmer in C++ . Help passing structure to function...?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, struct

Hi beginner programmer here :] not even sure of how to phrase this question. I'm working on a homework assignment and I can't seem to change the values of this structure I've created (budget2).

The goal of the program is to display the first structure, budget1, and find the difference between it and budget2 after the user inputs the values for budget2.

According to the debugger I'm not changing any values in budget2 when I input them using the inputData function and so when the showDiff function runs it just subtracts every value in budget2 from budget1 making all totals show up as 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


struct MonthlyBudget
{
    MonthlyBudget();
    double housing, utilities, householdExpenses, transportation, food, medical, insurance, entertainment, clothing, misc;

};


int main()
{
    HANDLE screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD position;

    void inputData(struct MonthlyBudget data);
    void displayData(struct MonthlyBudget);
    void showDiff(struct MonthlyBudget, struct MonthlyBudget); 
    struct MonthlyBudget budget1, budget2;


    displayData(budget1);
    inputData(budget2);
    showDiff(budget1, budget2);




    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

MonthlyBudget::MonthlyBudget()
{
    housing = 500.00;
    utilities = 150.00;
    householdExpenses = 65.00;
    transportation = 50.00;
    food = 250.00;
    medical = 30.00;
    insurance = 100.00;
    entertainment = 150.00;
    clothing = 75.00;
    misc = 50.00;
}

void displayData(struct MonthlyBudget data)
{
    cout << "\n\tBudget\n\n\t";
    cout << "$" << data.housing << "\n\n\t";
    cout << "$" << data.utilities << "\n\n\t";
    cout << "$" << data.householdExpenses << "\n\n\t";
    cout << "$" << data.transportation << "\n\n\t";
    cout << "$" << data.food << "\n\n\t";
    cout << "$" << data.medical << "\n\n\t";
    cout << "$" << data.insurance << "\n\n\t";
    cout << "$" << data.entertainment << "\n\n\t";
    cout << "$" << data.clothing << "\n\n\t";
    cout << "$" << data.misc << "\n\n\t";

}

void inputData(struct MonthlyBudget data)
{

    HANDLE screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD position;

    position.X = 15;
    position.Y = 3;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);

    cin >> data.housing;
    position.Y = 5;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);

    cin >> data.utilities;
    position.Y = 7;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);

    cin >> data.householdExpenses;
    position.Y = 9;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);

    cin >> data.transportation;
    position.Y = 11;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);

    cin >> data.food;
    position.Y = 13;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);

    cin >> data.medical;
    position.Y = 15;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);

    cin >> data.insurance;
    position.Y = 17;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);

    cin >> data.entertainment;
    position.Y = 19;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);

    cin >> data.clothing;
    position.Y = 21;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);

    cin >> data.misc;
    position.Y = 23;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);

}


void showDiff(struct MonthlyBudget data, struct MonthlyBudget data2)
{   
    HANDLE screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD position;

    position.X = 20;
    position.Y = 3;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);

    cout << (data.housing - data2.housing);

    position.Y = 5;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);
    cout << (data.utilities - data2.utilities);


    position.Y = 7;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);
    cout << (data.householdExpenses - data2.householdExpenses);

    position.Y = 9;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);
    cout << (data.transportation - data2.transportation);

    position.Y = 11;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);
    cout << (data.food - data2.food);

    position.Y = 13;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);
    cout << (data.medical - data2.medical);

    position.Y = 15;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);
    cout << (data.insurance - data2.insurance);

    position.Y = 17;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);
    cout << (data.entertainment - data2.entertainment);

    position.Y = 19;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);
    cout << (data.clothing - data2.clothing);

    position.Y = 21;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);
    cout << (data.misc - data2.misc);

    position.X = 5;
    position.Y = 23;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);

}
```

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong and any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

PS. I know my code must look ridiculous.

Comment: use pointer or reference to change the value in your inputData
void inputData(struct MonthlyBudget &data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing you structures by value.
This means whenever you call one of your functions your struct is copied and then passed to your function. So in your case `budget2` is copied and passed to `inputData`. But after you `inputData` is done `budget2` is still the same as the function worked on a copy.
You need to pass your structure either by a pointer or a ref. I would usggest using a reference in your case.
So your function should look like this:
`void inputData(MonthlyBudget& data);`

BTW:
You should really take a good book about c++ and read about pass by value or pass by reference.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks a lot. The description for the assignment says to pass by reference but I think I skipped over that part in the book or something. I'm using the book Starting Out with C++: Early Objects for an accelerated summer class. Trying to do the best I can but it makes my head hurt sometimes :/ . Thank you very much for the help.